# Standard deviation bar

Tags: bar-chart, standard-deviation

It's the first time that I post here, but I need help...
I'm trying to create some graphs in R, but for some reason I can't add the standard deviation bar on top of my bars.
[graph showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjOwp.png)

Here is the code that I'm using:
ggplot(qPCR_ABS, aes(x = Site, y = `correction per SWE (copies/m2)`, fill = layer)) +

- ```
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  ```
- ```
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = `correction per SWE (copies/m2)` - st_deviation,
  ```
- ```
                    ymax = `correction per SWE (copies/m2)` + st_deviation),
  ```
- ```
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.2) +
  ```
- ```
  facet_wrap(vars(DATE2), scales = "free_y")
  ```

How can I solve the problem and get the error bars on the top?
thanks

I would love to get the standard deviation bars on top of the bars. Some of the standard deviation bars are placed correctly, others not and I don't understand why